# CosmosDB Output Binding Failing

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to get my azure function (python v2 model) to create and write to a CosmosDB document. I get this error in my function app monitor every time it is executed:

`The CosmosDB connection string must be set either via the 'CosmosDB' IConfiguration connection string, via the CosmosDBAttribute.ConnectionStringSetting property or via CosmosDBOptions.ConnectionString.`

This is my code:

```
import azure.functions as func
import logging

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)

@app.cosmos_db_output(arg_name="outputDoc", database_name="gw-contact-db", container_name="gw-contact-lts", 
                      connection="CosmosDbConnectionString")
@app.route(route="BotLTSPush")
def BotLTSPush(req: func.HttpRequest, outputDoc: func.Out[func.Document]) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    try:
        body = req.get_json()
    except:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "Bad Request: Invalid JSON",
            status_code=400
        )
    
    if not body.keys() & {'locationId', 'contactId', 'calendarId', 'firstName', 'lastName', 
                          'phone', 'address', 'requestType', 'apptDate', 'apptTime', 'timezone'}:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "Bad Request: Missing required fields",
            status_code=400
        )
    
    phone = body['phone']
    body.pop('phone')
    body['id'] = phone

    outputDoc.set(func.Document.from_dict(body))
    return func.HttpResponse(
        "OK",
        status_code=200
    )
```

The app setting is confirmed to be correct. Any ideas?

Comment: Is `CosmosDbConnectionString` created in the App Settings "Connection Strings" section or on the other settings section?

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code in my environment I was also getting same error.

[image]

To resolve the issue, I just made changes in **host.json** file.
I changed **`extensionBundle`**  version from  **`"version": "[3.*, 4.0.0)"`** to **`"version": "[4.0.0, 5.0.0)"`**

**`host.json`:**

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.0.0,5.0.0)"
  }
}
```

**`local.settings.json`:**

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing",
    "CosmosDbConnectionString": "AccountEndpoint=https://xxxxxxxxx.documents.azure.com/;AccountKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;"
  }
}
```

It worked

**`Output`:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is 100% crazy, but it works. It's crazy that official Documentation provides non working code samples